# How to test JSON returned by controller using expected DTO?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-test

I use spring-test 5.0.7 and run into the next issue:

DTOs:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class SomeDTO {
    private String uid;
    private Object child;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class AnotherDTO {
    private String someField;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public static class TestController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/dto/{uid}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public SomeDTO findSomeObject(@PathVariable String uid) {
        return new SomeDTO(uid, new AnotherDTO("value"));
    }
}
```

And a test that is failing:

```
@Test
public void testControllerResult() throws Exception {
    SomeDTO dto = new SomeDTO(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new AnotherDTO("value"));

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/dto/{uid}", dto.getUid()))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$").value(dto));
}
```

Test logs:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$" 
Expected :TestTest.SomeDTO(uid=7817869a-eb9a-4491-a34b-a8006a643b6c, child=TestTest.AnotherDTO(someField=value))
Actual   :null
```

Is there any way to make it working without specifying type of field `SomeDTO.child`? I guess it does not work because `SomeDTO` does not provide information about field `child`(as soon as I make it `private AnotherDTO child`, test will pass), but it can be calculated at runtime.

Comment: why not validating the fields in `AnotherDTO` instead of complete object ?

Comment: @Deadpool, just because of convenience, anyway there may be a more complex model with the same issues somewhere inside, and in the worse case we will have to compare result field by field.

Comment: can you show the error messages with stack trace at least ?

Comment: @Deadpool, done

Comment: I'm just asking are you good in comparing complete json string instead of `dto`?

Comment: @Deadpool, yes, It might be a workaround, but comparing objects is just a better way, because if you verify json in only one test and JSON has changed, you need to fix only this test, but if you are comparing JSONs in each controller test and JSON has changed, you need to fix expected JSONs in all that tests. UPD: I think I got a better workaround: I can try to convert expected DTO to JSON string and to compare the string with result. Thanks.